# SQL Server 2008 sum values of a column, each in two tables based on key values of one table

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregates

Say I have 2 tables:

```
T1 with composite keys DOC, VER, SN1
DOC  VER  SN1  NME  ISU
---  ---  ---  ---  ---
AP   03   5    COM  2
AP   03   4    COM  3
AP   03   3    ITC  2 
AP   02   4    PUR  10 
AP   02   2    PUR  5
AW   03   2    EXP  4
AW   03   1    COM  8
AW   01   1    QAS  3

T2 with composite keys DOC, VER, SN2
DOC  VER  SN2  NME  RET
---  ---  ---  ---  ---
AP   03   3    ITC  1
AP   03   2    COM  1
AP   03   1    COM  3 
AP   02   2    PUR  6 
AP   02   1    PUR  4
AW   01   1    QAS  3
```

Result set must be:

```
DOC  VER  NME  TISU  TRET
---  ---  ---  ----  ----
AP   03   COM  5     4
AP   03   ITC  2     1
AP   02   PUR  15    10
AW   03   EXP  4     null
AW   03   COM  8     null 
AW   01   QAS  3     0
```

Basically this sums up ISU columns for each distinct DOC, VER, NME and
sum up RET columns for each distinct DOC, VER, NME values.

I have tried the following

```
select T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, SUM(T1.ISU) as TISU, 
       (select sum(T2.RET) from T2) as TRET
from T1
group by T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME
```

This correctly sums up the TISU columns but not TRET columns as it is repeating the value it find at the first sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `where` to your correlated subquery:

```
select T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, SUM(T1.ISU) as TISU, (
        select sum(T2.RET) 
        from T2 
        where T1.DOC = T2.DOC
          and T1.REV = T2.REV
          and T1.NME = T2.NME
          ) as TRET
from T1
group by T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME
```

You could also join on a subquery that perform your aggregations like so:

```
select T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, SUM(T1.ISU) as TISU, T2.TRET
from T1
  left join (
    select T2.DOC, T2.REV, T2.NME, SUM(T2.RET) as TRET
    from T2
    group by T2.DOC, T2.REV, T2.NME
  ) as T1
     on T1.DOC = T2.DOC
    and T1.REV = T2.REV
    and T1.NME = T2.NME 
group by T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, T2.TRET
```

or join two subqueries like so:

```
select T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, T1.TISU, T2.TRET
from (
    select T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME, SUM(T1.ISU) as TISU
    from T1
    group by T1.DOC, T1.REV, T1.NME
  ) as T1
  left join (
    select T2.DOC, T2.REV, T2.NME, SUM(T2.RET) as TRET
    from T2
    group by T2.DOC, T2.REV, T2.NME
  ) as T1
     on T1.DOC = T2.DOC
    and T1.REV = T2.REV
    and T1.NME = T2.NME
```

Comment: yes I see the first solution minutes after I posted lol. I missed the where part in the correlated query. I will check the other 2 options you suggested. Thanks much, you have provided more than I asked  for.